# How do I customize the Share Dialog, specifically to remove the "Share With People" section in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I need to customize the Share Dialog, specifically to remove the "Share With People" section.

Hi, my customer wants me to remove the "Share With People" section of the Share Dialog so that the user is only presented with the link to their custom view. I've noticed in the samples at https://help.tableau.com/samples that if I open the Share Dialog it only has the link which is what I want. Plus they have the social media links, which I don't really want, still shows customization possibilities.

Looking at the code, I don't see anything fancy that was done to accomplish this, so I have come to the conclusion that help.tableau might be a special version????

NOTE:

my version: 2020.1 (Out of my control)
OS: Linux (AWS instance)

Images attached:

- helpDialog.jpeg (dialog from help.tableau)
- myDialog.jpeg (dialog from my integration)

I have complete control over the server and any integration code needed, I just can't find the fix. Any ideas would be appreciated.

[MyDialog.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUuTr.png)
[HelpDialog.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld2Lu.png)

Answer (score 1):

In the end, this can't be done.  I removed the button from Tableua using the parameters and wrote my own "share" outside of tableau.